# How make Python stop a running dash server after a minute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, localhost, plotly-dash

On my local machine, I am using `plotly` with Dash.
I run the python file from the command line (Windows Powershell or cmd.exe but it behaves the same on both) and would wish to

- let it stop the dash server after a minute or so, or
- let it stop after typing "yes" on an input("question").

While the output is fine, trouble is, it does not even reach any line further down after app.run_server(...) unless I type Ctrl-C on the shell to let it quit.

I have in mind something like *`app.run_server(debug=True, runtime = 360)` should exist but extensive googling didn't help...

I have also tried using *[subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess)* but it was of no avail. I simply don't know how and where to start... Like, how to connect things to it, or even insert a python command, such as `app.run_server(...)`, inside of `Popen()` as a shell command what it is not, after all.

Here is a minimum working example, how should I modify this to make it stop?

```
#testingdash.py
import os
import signal

from dash import Dash, html, dcc

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Textarea(
        id='textarea-example',
        value='Lorem ipsum test working example',
        style={'width': '100%', 'height': 300},
    ),
    html.Div(id='textarea-example-output', style={'whiteSpace': 'pre-line'})
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
    print("Does not even reach this before ctrl-C")
    #quit()
    os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `app.run_server(debug=True)` is a blocking call, meaning that it will block the execution of any code following it until the server is manually stopped.

As far as I know, you can run the Dash server in a separate thread or process to achieve this. Maybe try something like:

```
import time
import threading

from dash import Dash, html, dcc

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Textarea(
        id='textarea-example',
        value='Lorem ipsum test working example',
        style={'width': '100%', 'height': 300},
    ),
    html.Div(id='textarea-example-output', style={'whiteSpace': 'pre-line'})
])

def run_dash():
    app.run_server(debug=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Run Dash in a separate thread
    dash_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_dash)
    dash_thread.start()

    # Run for 60 seconds
    time.sleep(60)

    # Stop the Dash server by terminating the entire program
    print("Stopping Dash server...")
    #lol, you sure you know what you're doing?
    os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)
```

Comment: Seems that dash_thread.start() prevents dash from starting at all, no connection in browser page; time.sleep is done but I get an exception [have to make it short here]
```
Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/

Exception in thread Thread-1 (run_dash):
in (my file) def run_dash():
    app.run_server(debug = True) [...]
  File "~\Lib\signal.py", line 56, in signal
    handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
ValueError: signal only works in main thread of the main interpreter
```